# Ionic/Phonegap does not play html5 video, but native browsers do

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video, ionic-framework

I have an issue with android playing HTML5 video. The webpage perfectly works in the native android browser, and in Chome on my Samsung Galaxy TAB 3. But when I create an Ionic/Phonegap application from the same source, the video just won't play.

The player renders fine, and I can click play, but when I do, nothing happens. There are also no error messages visible in the console.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<video class="chapter-video" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source src="content/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Did you try to check the GapDebug console?

Comment: You may need to include an OGV and a WebM source as well as the .mp4, so that the native browser can read the correct video codec

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple myApp tabs project and had the hardest time adding local videos. What ended up working for me was to just add '/android_asset/' to the front of the local video.

```
                <video customvideo>
                    <source src="/android_asset/www/img/small.mp4"/>
                    <!--<source src="../img/small.mp4"/>-->
                </video>
```

The actual path to the video is the commented out code, the code that works as a native app after running the 'ionic run android' command is uncommented.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Most audio & video element issues with Android are non-existant when using Crosswalk (Chromium webview) with your Ionic project.

**Disclaimer:** Adding Crosswalk increases app binary size.

Make a backup before adding Crosswalk to your project.

`ionic browser add crosswalk`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<video>` tag, try using HTML `<iframe>` tag to embed another document within the current HTML. See the example below:

```
<div class="item" >      
     <div class="video-container">
        <iframe src="{{ image.video }}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="300"></iframe>
     </div>
</div>
```

Read about iframe here: [w3school iframe link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)